# How do you use RoutingState.NavigateCommandFor<T> properly

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I was trying to follow the view model navigation pattern established in the [XamForms Playground](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/Playground-XamForms/Views/TestView.xaml.cs) but ran into some troubles getting it to work properly.

Given the following code, you can see what the problem is:

```
// Router = new RoutingState();
// Navigate = Router.NavigateCommandFor<MyViewModel>();

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Navigate)
    //.Do(x => x.CanExecuteObservable.Subscribe())
    .BindTo(this, x => x.NavigateButton.Command);

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Router)
    .BindTo(this, x => x.ViewHost.Router);
```

If we simply bind the `Navigate` command to the button's `Command` object, it's initial `CanExecute` state is `false` and there is never an adjustment to that initial state. If I uncomment the `Do` code above then we *force* an initial state to be computed and the button enables itself appropriately.

Obviously, this does not look correct to me, as you would expect that the initial `CanExecute` state would be true (at least after the UI is loaded).

What is worse, is that this appears to be a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) because if you ever check the `CanExecute` state of the `RoutingState.Navigate` or the `MyViewModel.Navigate` commands (with `CanExecute(null)`), they will return `true` and the button will display enabled upon continuation (**NOTE** you only have to check the view model command to enable the button).

I want to apply this pattern correctly but I am quite confused as to the why this seemingly simple pattern is failing for this scenario. Can anyone confirm or deny that this is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some more research on this question I was able to clear up some confusion, but still not quite answer the question. Below are my discoveries:

First, the proper way to bind a command according to the [online documentation](http://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/stable/basics/bindings/), is

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Navigate, x => x.NavigateButton);
```

The code sample I posted above should look something like this, if it were in the proper (current) ReactiveUI framework:

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, x => x.Navigate, x => x.NavigateButton);
// note that I also used a "hack" binding for the router above, this is the correct binding strategy
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Router, x => x.ViewHost.Router);
```

In order to (as seamlessly as possible) create navigation commands for routable view models, I have created some extensions methods (temporarily suffixed with numbers) that perform the `CanExecuteObservable` subscribe before returning the command. At this time I'm not sure what the best choice for an extension method would be, but I'm leaning towards numbers 3 and 4 as they produce a strongly typed generic command (which give automatic observability, compared to `IReactiveCommand`).

```
// all the NavigateCommandFor extensions also provide the ability to inject the navigate command itself (the default Navigate, or NavigateAndReset), 
// the dependency resolver (still defaults to Locator.Current), and the type resolution contract
public static partial class ExtensionMethods
{
    // simple extension to inline the subscription
    public static T SubscribeToCommand<T>(this T This)
        where T : IReactiveCommand
    {
        This.CanExecuteObservable.Subscribe();

        return This;
    }

    // this was my first attempt without actually analyzing the current NavigateCommandFor source
    public static IReactiveCommand<object> NavigateCommandFor1<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable, _ => navigationCommand.ExecuteAsync((dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract)));

        return ret.SubscribeToCommand();
    }

    // After looking at the NavigateCommandFor source, this is minimalistic adaptation 
    // except ajusting the return value to be the generic interface with an object type param
    public static IReactiveCommand<object> NavigateCommandFor2<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = new ReactiveCommand<object>(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable, x => Observable.Return(x));

        ret.Select(_ => (dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract)).InvokeCommand(navigationCommand);

        return ret.SubscribeToCommand();
    }

    // My attempt to optimize the return value to be strongly typed
    // I'm not sure if this has any implications
    public static IReactiveCommand<T> NavigateCommandFor3<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = new ReactiveCommand<T>(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable, _ => Observable.Return((dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract)));

        ret.InvokeCommand(navigationCommand);

        return ret.SubscribeToCommand();
    }

    // The original source allows for un-registered view models to be new()'d
    // this extension provides that same ability, but again with a strongly typed return value
    public static IReactiveCommand<T> NavigateCommandFor4<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel, new()
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = new ReactiveCommand<T>(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable, _ => Observable.Return((T)((IRoutableViewModel)(dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract) ?? new T())));

        ret.InvokeCommand(navigationCommand);

        return ret.SubscribeToCommand();
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure which of these extensions is the most appropriate, or why subscribing to `CanExecuteObservable` is necessary (I assume it is a bug in `ReactiveCommand`), but the above could be considered a viable work-around to the problem I initially posted (however not really an answer to question as I still think this is not the *proper* usage of `NavigateCommandFor`).

Answer (score 0):

I found a much cleaner method of seeding the `CanExecute` state by simply calling `Skip(1)` on the observable when building the reactive command. This reduces the code a small bit for the extension methods, giving us the following:

```
// The key fix here is to Skip(1) on CanExecuteObservable so that we seed the state
// all the NavigateCommandFor extensions also provide the ability to inject the navigate command itself (the default Navigate, or NavigateAndReset), 
// the dependency resolver (still defaults to Locator.Current), and the type resolution contract
public static partial class ExtensionMethods
{
    // After looking at the NavigateCommandFor source, this is minimalistic adaptation 
    // except ajusting the return value to be the generic interface with an object type param
    public static IReactiveCommand<object> PatchedNavigateCommandFor<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = new ReactiveCommand<object>(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable.Skip(1), x => Observable.Return(x));

        ret.Select(_ => (dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract)).InvokeCommand(navigationCommand);

        return ret;
    }

    // My attempt to optimize the return value to be strongly typed
    // I'm not sure if this has any implications
    public static IReactiveCommand<T> StrongNavigateCommandFor<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = new ReactiveCommand<T>(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable.Skip(1), _ => Observable.Return((dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract)));

        ret.InvokeCommand(navigationCommand);

        return ret;
    }

    // The original source allows for un-registered view models to be new()'d
    // this extension provides that same ability, but again with a strongly typed return value
    public static IReactiveCommand<T> StrongNewNavigateCommandFor<T>(this RoutingState This, IReactiveCommand<object> navigationCommand = null, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver = null, string contract = null)
        where T : IRoutableViewModel, new()
    {
        navigationCommand = navigationCommand ?? This.Navigate;

        var ret = new ReactiveCommand<T>(navigationCommand.CanExecuteObservable.Skip(1), _ => Observable.Return((T)((IRoutableViewModel)(dependencyResolver ?? Locator.Current).GetService<T>(contract) ?? new T())));

        ret.InvokeCommand(navigationCommand);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

I believe this is the most appropriate answer and I have additionally [posted an issue](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/908) with my findings to the ReactiveUI github project.